# Nested ObservableCollections throwing exception when modified on different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm using a TreeView that has an ItemsSource bound to an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel. I'm using a HierarchicalDataTemplate that has its ItemsSource bound to another ObservableCollection. Both of these ObservableCollections are being updated dynamically from a different thread.

```
<TreeView x:Name="planeView" BorderThickness="0" MaxHeight="500" ItemsSource="{Binding Planes}"  SelectedItemChanged="treeview_OnSelectedItemChanged">
   <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Plane}" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlaneId}" />
            <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Messages.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
            <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
         </StackPanel>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Message}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeStamp}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The net result is a Tree where the top level nodes are dynamic and so are the contents of those nodes.

As I started developing this with a single ObservableCollecction I ran into the exception:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its Source Collection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread

I found multiple sources that suggested using `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(...)`

That solved my problem and I kept on developing. However, when I nested them and made them both dynamic. That exception came back. I made sure that I enabled synchronization on both observable collections. However, I still got the exception, and usually the exception was after one or two items were displayed visually in the UI. (nothing consistent) So it seems like some sort of race condition, but I don't know how to solve it.

Below is my ViewModel and a couple of supporting classes.

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
  private object _lock = new object();

  public ObservableCollection<Plane> Planes { get; set; }

  public MyViewModel()
  {
     Planes = new ObservableCollection<Plane>();
     BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Planes, _lock);
     MessageSystem.Subscribe<PlaneInformationMessage>(HandlePlaneMessage);
  }

  // this method is executed on a different thread
  public void HandlePlaneMessage(PlaneInformationMessage planeMsg)
  {
     Message msg = new Message();

     // set the timestamp
     string timeStampString;
     if (planeMsg.TimeOfDay.HasValue)
     {
        timeStampString = planeMsg.TimeOfDay.Value.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
     }
     else
     {
        timeStampString = "--:--:--";
     }

     msg.TimeStamp = timeStampString;
     msg.Content = planeMsg.OriginalMessageContents;

     var plane = new Plane();
     plane.PlaneId = planeMsg.TailNumber.ToString();

     int index = Planes.IndexOf(plane);

     if (index < 0)
     {
        plane.Messages.Add(msg);
        Planes.Insert(0, plane);
     }
     else
     {
        Debug.WriteLine(msg.TimeStamp);
        Planes[index].Messages.Insert(0, msg); // This line throws the exception!!
     }
  }
```

Support classes:

```
public class Plane : IEquatable<Plane>
{
  private object _lock = new object();

  public string PlaneId { get; set; }

  public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }

  public Plane()
  {
     Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
     BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Messages, _lock);
  }

  public bool Equals(Plane other)
  {
     if (PlaneId == other.PlaneId)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
  }
```

}

```
public class Message
{
  public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
  public string Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You either move back on the UI thread to update it, or you use a custom collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use Dispatcher.Invoke method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx

Try do your update like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Planes[index].Messages.Insert(0, msg));
```